# Increase every character in particular column to next characters - hive

Tags: hive, decode, hiveql

I am working on hive. I want to decode all records in `name` column by increasing every character to count 3. Example if name is `abc` i want `cde`. How can I do this using hive?

Comment: What values should x,y and z get?

Comment: xyz should get abc, but not special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :** A much simpler solution : with `TRANSLATE` function.

```
SELECT TRANSLATE (name,
                  'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                  'defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc')
  FROM yourtable;
```

**OLD Approach** (Don't use )

You could use a combination of splitting, converting to ascii, adding reconverting and joining them back into a string.

```
WITH t AS
  ( SELECT 'abc' AS name
       UNION ALL
  SELECT 'pqr' AS name
  ) ,
  ASC AS
  (SELECT name,
    ASCII(t1.letter) ascii_number
  FROM t LATERAL VIEW explode(split( REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'(.)' , '$1|') , '\\|') ) t1 AS letter
  )
SELECT name,
  concat_ws('',collect_set( DECODE(unhex(hex(ascii_number+3)), 'US-ASCII') ) ) as name_plus_3
FROM ASC
GROUP BY name;
```

**O/p:**

```
name name_plus_3
----  ----------
abc def        
pqr stu
```

Comment: @prasanna : Did you understand the logic used? Are you sure how to use it on your table? I have shown this example with a CTE . You need o use it on your table considering the part after the first CTE's comma. Off course it will work for all records. Please try and let me know. For the the 3 scenarios xyz to abc, you may use additional criteria

Comment: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Recursive cte reminder_type_master detected (cycle: reminder -> reminder).` i am getting this error

Comment: i am able to do now. but stuck up with xyz.

Comment: @Kaushik_Nayak sir please help with this.

Comment: @prasanna. I'm using app now and away from computer. You may try with some additional case blocks for xyz . I will come back in a while

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i am trying but still i am not able to do it.

Comment: @prasanna : Please note I have added a much simpler solution. There is no need to use the previous approach. I will just keep it in the answer but you may ignore it.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Thank you, but newly translated column is not shwing up with existing table, i need to append that new column or replace with existing column. please help me with this sir.

Comment: @prasanna : Do you mean you want to update the table?

Comment: yep sir @Kaushik_Nayak

Comment: @prasanna : You may google/ refer to this  link or post a separate question for others to answer . I'm not too familiar with hive update table. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/51195/how-to-update-hive-table.html . But the logic to modify the column would be same.